# Defining Multiple Variables with Equal Value and Concatenating

Tags: php

In this **PHP Code** I want to define a **static value** to **multiple variables**
while **concatenating** the string to its parent variable like the following code here

```
$Alpha = "Alpha-";
$Beta = "Beta-";
$Gamma = "Gamma-";
function func($vars, $number, $letter) {
    switch ($number) {
        case 1:
            foreach ($vars as $var) {
                $var .= "1";
            }
                break;
        case 2:
            foreach ($vars as $var) {
                $var .= "2";
            }
                break;
        case 3:
            foreach ($vars as $var) {
                $var .= "3";
            }
    }
    switch ($letter) {
        case "a":
            foreach ($vars as $var) {
                $var .= "A";
            }
                break;
        case "b":
            foreach ($vars as $var) {
                $var .= "B";
            }
                break;
        case "c":
            foreach ($vars as $var) {
                $var .= "C";
            }
    }
    return $var;
}
func([$Alpha, $Beta, $Gamma], 1, "a");
$Alpha .= "-haEND";
$Beta .= "-taEND";
$Gamma .= "-maEND";

echo $Alpha;
echo '<br>';
echo $Beta;
echo '<br>';
echo $Gamma;
```

I expect the result to be

**Alpha-1A-haEND**

**Beta-1A-taEND**

**Gamma-1A-maEND**

But i don't get the **1A**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to update a value of a copy of your variable (in each foreach). To update the value, you have to pass them by reference in the loop.

Then, you are not using your return value.

You could try something like this. Note the `&` in foreach, the using of return, and `list()` to extract your data from the array.

```
$Alpha = "Alpha-";
$Beta = "Beta-";
$Gamma = "Gamma-";
function func($vars, $number, $letter) {
    switch ($number) {
        case 1:
            foreach ($vars as &$var) {$var .= "1"; }
                break;
        case 2:
            foreach ($vars as &$var) {$var .= "2"; }
                break;
        case 3:
            foreach ($vars as &$var) {$var .= "3"; } 
    }

    switch ($letter) {
        case "a":
            foreach ($vars as &$var) {$var .= "A"; }
                break;
        case "b":
            foreach ($vars as &$var) {$var .= "B"; }
                break;
        case "c":
            foreach ($vars as &$var) {$var .= "C"; }
    }
    return $vars;
}

$arr = func([$Alpha, $Beta, $Gamma], 1, "a");
list($Alpha, $Beta, $Gamma) = $arr ;

$Alpha .= "-haEND";
$Beta .= "-taEND";
$Gamma .= "-maEND";

echo $Alpha;
echo '<br>';
echo $Beta;
echo '<br>';
echo $Gamma;
```

Outputs:

```
Alpha-1A-haEND
Beta-1A-taEND
Gamma-1A-maEND
```

Comment: What is this `&$var` exactly? Can't find any explaination about it.

Comment: @Toleo When you use `foreach ($vars as $var)`, `$var` is a copy of the value, and change its values doesn't change the value in the `$vars` array. Using `&` will *not* made a copy but use the variable in the array.

Comment: @Toleo Another approch is to use `foreach ($vars as $key => $var) { $vars[$key] .= "a"; }`.

Comment: Would using `$key` not require me to use `list()`?

Comment: @Toleo The other approch is for the reference, not for the rest of the code. You have to use `$key` or `&$var`.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an awful lot of repeated code here - there's no need to use six separate loops to append a number and letter to some strings.

PHP's [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) method lets you apply a user-defined callback to each member of an array, which can cut this down dramatically, and also removes the need to add additional case statements if you need to expand the set of supported numbers/letters:

```
$Alpha = "Alpha-";
$Beta = "Beta-";
$Gamma = "Gamma-";

$values = [&$Alpha, &$Beta, &$Gamma];
$number = 1;
$letter = 'a';

array_walk($values, function (&$item) use ($number, $letter) {
    $item .= $number . strtoupper($letter);
});

$Alpha .= "-haEND";
$Beta .= "-taEND";
$Gamma .= "-maEND";
```

As @Syscall mentioned, the important difference is that the elements are passed to the function by reference - your original code was modifying copies, rather than the originals.

See https://eval.in/949087

Comment: I see, Just discovered the `&$` now; I'm aiming to make my PHP page shorter by wrapping the `switch()` into a `function`, Is it possible to wrap the `array_walk()` in it? Since i find it has its own function by itself And i think two function inside each other is a bad idea for performance, And i have to use `switch()` anyway instead of `$item .= $number . strtoupper($letter);`